# why would I get a "is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level." only on the ELSE of an IF THEN ELSE block?

Tags: vb.net, scope

I am an utter newbie with VB.NET, so be gentle with my stupidity ;-)

I have a simple IF THEN ELSE block which checks for the presence of a querystring and then checks if it is set. The idea is that if no querystring, the form is empty and people can enter a new form. If there is a querystring and it isn't blank, a db query for the form data occurs, fields are populated and a user can update the form.

so here is my code block.

```
      Dim strQueryStingCheck As String
      If Not (Request.QueryString("pid") Is Nothing) Then ' is there a querystring? 
        If Request.QueryString("pid").ToString <> "" Then ' does it have a value?
            strQueryStingCheck = "u"
            Session("travelauthno") = Request.QueryString("pid")
        Else
            strQueryStringCheck = "e"
            Session("travelauthno") = ""
        End If
    End If
```

I am getting the "Variable is not declared; it may be inaccessible due to its protection level" for strQueryStringCheck ONLY on the Else code block - that is when I set strQueryStringCheck to "e". I can't figure it out.

I've looked at other posts, particularly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289426/vb-2010-variable-is-not-declared-it-may-be-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection). and it was helpful. I can make the error go away, but I want to understand why I am getting it in the first place. I declared it within the subroutine. And if I was doing something wrong, shouldn't it throw an error on BOTH blocks of the IF THEN ELSE block? It doesn't when I set strQueryStringCheck to "u". Why only in the ELSE block?

PS I am coding in Visual Studio 2010. Also if I make it a simple IF...THEN...ELSE w/o nesting, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have a typo in your IF branch. In if you have `strQueryStingCheck`, in else you have `strQueryStringCheck`. You are missing a `r` in the first one. You have the same typo in your variable declaration.

Comment: yep, someone else here just noticed it. Very embarrassed!

Comment: @FatGUyFromQueens If this solved your problem. Make sure that you accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully ...  Dim strQueryStingCheck As String

but in the else :  strQueryStringCheck = "e"

Their is a R missing in your dim ...

Comment: yeah, just caught it. Thanks everyone for your help!