# Simple "not declared" error

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am getting not declared error when using a timer class.

[image]

```
    Module module2


        Public Class TimerRequest
            Private Shared aTimer As Timer
            Public Shared Sub Main()
                aTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(50000) ' 5 minutes
                AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
                aTimer.Enabled = True
            End Sub
            Private Shared Sub OnTimedEvent(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
                Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
                Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.example.com/useragent.php")

            End Sub
        End Class



        Sub main()


            Dim o As Object
            o = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


o.Navigate2("http://bit.do/T8Vn", "", "", "", "Referer: " & result & vbCrLf & "User-Agent: " & result2)

            Next

        End Sub

    End Module
```

Where did I do mistake ?

Comment: you need to learn about [Scope in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx)  the error message says it all - "result" is not accessible where you are trying to use it.

Comment: You're declaring those variable inside OnTimedEvent. They are only visible from within that function, and so 'undeclared' when used inside Sub main().

Comment: Use a field instead of a local variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB 2010 'variable' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's protection level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289426/vb-2010-variable-is-not-declared-it-may-be-inaccessible-due-to-its-protectio)

Answer (score 0):

you must change the variables result and result2 accessibility, because they are only accessible in OnTimedEvent procedure.
move them under Public Class.