# 'drpApp' is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpAppType" runat="server" Width="300px">
</asp:DropDownList>

Sub FillAppoinmentType()
        Dim D As New DBMain
        D.OpenEMRCon()
        Try
            Dim Str As String
            Str = "SELECT AppTypeID, AppName FROM [z_AppointmentType] WHERE ISNULL(IsDeleted,0)=0 AND ISNULL(AllowTeleMedicine,0)=1"
            Dim set1 As New DataSet
            D.FillDataSet(set1, Str)

            ViewState("myds") = set1
            drpAppType.DataSource = set1.Tables(0)
            drpAppType.DataBind()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Z.WriteError(ex, lblmsg)
        End Try
        D.CloseEMRCon()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB 2010 'variable' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's protection level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289426/vb-2010-variable-is-not-declared-it-may-be-inaccessible-due-to-its-protectio)

Comment: curious as to why this is tagged with c#? While you're editing that, maybe put 4 spaces at the start of every code line too (select the code, click the {} button above the text box)